# Dynamic problem Finite Element

Tags: finite-element

[image]

Hi guys! I am working on a dynamics problem that I am not really sure how to solve it. Can anyone help me? The professor gave as a hint that we should compute the stiffness matrix of a linear element and then the stiffness matrix of a quadratic element.

THanks!

Comment: Your question is too vague. What have you tried already, which part of the process are you stuck in, etc? If your question is "Can you solve this homework for me?", then you will not have much luck here. If your question is "I am trying to solve this homework and there is one step I do not understand; can you explain it to me?" then please rephrase your question.

Comment: Hint: Eigenvalues

Answer (score 1):

To add onto Christian Clason's hint; as you'd do in a fundamental vibrations course, if you have a mass and stiffness matrix, you should be able to express and solve the eigenvalue problem for the system's natural frequencies.